# Using "soft delete" with HABTM relationships in CakePHP 2

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, has-and-belongs-to-many, cakephp-model

Using HABTM tables in CakePHP 2.x, what is the best way to use a "soft delete" technique (i.e. having "deleted" boolean field within a join table) so that when removing associations the "deleted" field will only be updated to "1" instead of the row being deleted?

An example is a database of Movies that can be part of one or more Genres. All tables have a "deleted" field so that no data is ever removed from the database, only the "deleted" field is updated to 1 or 0 as appropriate:

#### Movie

- id
- name
- deleted

#### Genre

- id
- name
- deleted

#### GenreMovie

- genre_id
- movie_id
- deleted

When adding or editing a Movie, the user can select one or more Genres to associate the Movie with. If a previously associated Genre is removed from a Movie, "deleted" would be set to "1".  If the same Genre is then re-associated with the Movie, it will be updated back to "0".

We've tried the SoftDelete behaviour from CakeDC's Utils plugin - https://github.com/CakeDC/utils - which works great for Movie and Genre, but for us doesn't seem to work for the join table GenreMovie, which continues to have rows completely deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a [deleteQuery](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm) in your relationships.

Also to prevent deletion of records in the join table, look at this:

> unique: boolean or string keepExisting.
>
> ```
>    If true (default value) cake will first delete existing relationship records in the foreign keys table before inserting new ones. Existing associations need to be passed again when updating.
>    When false, cake will insert the relationship record, and that no join records are deleted during a save operation.
>    When set to keepExisting, the behavior is similar to true, but existing associations are not deleted.
> ```

Comment: Thanks, can you provide an example of how the deleteQuery would look?   The CakePHP documentation appears to lack any usage examples.